# Invalid hook call in class component when I try to use useParams to get the param from url

Tags: reactjs

Do you have any idea how can I use useParams to get the parameter from the url in a class component? I get this error: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
I tried adding the serviceID at this.state, but that didn't work either.

```
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{<LocationOnIcon color="primary"/>}</div>;

class SimpleMap extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      resdate : new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10),
    }
  }
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 59.95,
      lng: 30.33
    },
    greatPlaceCoords: {lat:45.756659,
    lng:21.228703},
    zoom: 11,
  };
 
  handleReservation = async () => {

    let params = useParams();
    await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/reservation',
      headers: {},
      data: {
        serviceID: params.serviceID,
        userID: Cookies.get('userID'),
        reservationDate: this.state.resdate
      }
  })}

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: '50vh', width: '35%', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'apiKey' }}
          defaultCenter={ AnyReactComponent ? this.props.greatPlaceCoords: this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
          lat={45.756659}
          lng={21.228703}
        >
          <AnyReactComponent
            {...this.props.greatPlaceCoords}
           text= "{<LocationOnIcon/>} location"
/>
        </GoogleMapReact>
          <Button onClick={this.handleReservation} 
           Make a reservation
          </Button>
        <Booking/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleMap;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `withRouter` to get param in the component

```
import { withRouter } from "path/to/withRouter";

export default withRouter(SimpleMap);
```

And using `this.props.match.params` to get your params:

```
const params = this.props.params;
```

UPDATE: Because you are using `react-router` v6 and it not support for Class. So you should create a `withRouter` in your app:

withRouter.jsx:

```
export function withRouter( Child ) {
  return ( props ) => {
    const params = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return <Child { ...props } params ={ params } />;
  }
}
```

And you need to add `super(props)` in `constructor`

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resdate : new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10),
    }
  }
```

Comment: With this I get an error. withRouter is not exported from react-router

Comment: What version of `react-router` you are using?

Comment: react-router 6.0.0 and react-router-dom 6.0.0

Comment: The whole project is based on that version. I cannot change it.

Comment: Like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-fog-mssev?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I added this at the end... 
export default withRouter(SimpleMap);  Still doesn't work. params undefined

Comment: No. Create a file `withRouter`. Then iport and using it in your component

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      resdate : new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10),
    }
    this.handleReservation = this.handleReservation.bind(this);
  }
```

then you get params

```
this.props.match.params
```

Comment: I get "props is not defined"

Comment: ```11 | class SimpleMap extends Component {
  12 |   constructor(){
> 13 |     super(props);
  14 |     this.state = {
  15 |       resdate : new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10),
  16 |     } ```

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') .

Comment: try to bind inside constructor like this ->
         this.handleReservation = this.handleReservation.bind(this);
check updated one

Comment: same error... Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params').

Comment: `url: 'http://localhost:3001/reservation',
  36 | headers: {},
  37 | data: {
> 38 |   serviceID: this.props.match.params,
     | ^  39 |   userID: Cookies.get('userID'),
  40 |   reservationDate: this.state.resdate
  41 | }`

Comment: what does  -> this.props.match  return  in console ?

Comment: it returns undefined

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use hooks in class components. If you must, you can define a wrapper component that includes the hook, then pass that along as a prop:

```
export default (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
 
  return (
    <SimpleMap {...props} params={params} />
  );
}
```